# How to schedule a picture into an existing album on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-photos

I have a fan page with different photo albums. I’d like to add more pictures to each album by using the schedule feature of Facebook. How do I do this and make sure that the picture  I schedule for a later post is saved in the correct album?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible using Facebook. Facebook only allows you to schedule photos to the Page timeline / wall photos.

You will have to use a 3rd party app. A lot of them offer this functionality. I can recommend you [Publer](https://publer.me). Besides scheduling photo to existing albums, it also allows you to schedule **new** albums.

Disclaimer: I'm the founder of [Publer](https://publer.me).